# TemplateField decimal places and thousand separator

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, separator

I am using .net 2.0 and have a gridview with a templatefield where I have a label that has a text and a tooltip. The text is a numeric value and the tooltip is a description of the coin of that value.
I want that value to have 2 decimal places and a decimal separator. I have achieved that with the code below. But this has one problem, when the is 9,00 for example, I get 09,00

For larger values everything is ok. When I use # I get an error stating "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <fv:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
                     ToolTip='<%# Eval("Coin") %>' 
                     Text='<%# Eval("Value", "{0:0,0.00}") %>'> 
                </fv:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Any suggestions to solve this small issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `0` inside the format is a required digit.
Use `#` instead for an optional digit.

Example: `{0:#,0.00`}.